# Setting up a database for Yii 2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to install an app written in Yii 2 on my local computer. I installed composer and initiated the app with:

```
php /path/to/yii-application/init
```

Now I need to *"create a new database and adjust the `components['db']` configuration in `common/config/main-local.php` accordingly."*

I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: You probably have no database installed, so why not head right to [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) and download the community mysql server which is open source and free to use. Follow the installation instructions and take a look at their how tos and tutorials. I bet they also have some infos on how to create a new database and how to access it.
Also an advice: don't be afraid to ask others (you did already by posting here) but as far as I understood, you are there to learn, and the senior devs are there to help you.

Comment: Others have already answered your question but I just wanted to say, don't be afraid to ask questions, getting immersed is the best way to learn and good luck!

Comment: OK, seriously. 90% of this question has nothing to do with the question. Please narrow that down and get to the point in a paragraph or two. Your backstory is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @deceze, please just stop. I do not want your help.

Answer (score 4):

1) Create database on your server.
2) Open `common/config/main-local.php`

Edit components to:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE_NAME',
        'username' => 'DATABASE_USER',
        'password' => 'DATABASE_PASSWORD',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

If using MAMP with **mac** then edit dsn line to :

```
'dsn' => 'mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=DATABASE_NAME'
```

Comment: For mac edit dsn line to :

'dsn' => 'mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname="herecomesdbname"',

Because i had a problem with that, i was stuck for a long time because of using mac.

2 others had the same problem with mac.

Comment: @OussamaFahchouch. Included your suggestion.

Comment: Note: Mac instructions only apply if using MAMP.